# How can I change the column order of a SQL Server Report Services report at runtime?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I would like to change the sequence of the headers/columns of an `*.rdlc` report at runtime based on e.g. user preference settings. I found that you can make some columns invisible, but I haven't found a way to change the order of the columns. I am using the ReportViewer control in an ASP.NET web page. And at runtime in this case would mean that the layout can change during two page requests. I read somewhere that you could configure the rdlc xml dynamically or use the rdl object model to create the report definition dynamically as part of the request handling.

The following example should will hopefully explain better what I am trying to do:

Default report column layout of a table or matrix:

```
Date   Item   Price
```

Dynamically changed order of columns at runtime:

```
Item   Price   Date
```

Comment: If the columns are generated automatically from a matrix, then you can order them following some logic. If it's a table with static columns, I don't think you can sort them at runtime

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've ever done something similar is through parameters.

```
Header cell expression: =Parameters!Column1.Label
Row cell expression:    =Fields(Parameters!Column1.Value).Value
```

Where the `label` parameter is the column header and the value is the Field name in your dataset. So in your example there would be 3 Column parameters, all with the available label/value of `Date`, `Item`, `Price` and changing the parameters will determine the column contents.