# How to move column in Precision Design by VisualStudio at RunTime?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, report, axapta, ssrs-2012

I'm doing a modification in *Precision Design*, I'm using *Visual Studio Ultimate 2013*.

I have a *Tablix* I need to move a column, the column already exist, I want to move it in *ReportDesign* more to the right.

I want to do this work : 
[image: move column]

I want to move and change the order of the columns at run time.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some more detail, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to move and change the order of the columns at run time?

Comment: Hi @ FH-Inway, yes, I want to move and change the order of the columns at run time. very thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] this information into your question because comments may not be read by others. You may also want to add a tag for SSRS because this is not really tied to AX. Also take a look at [How can I change the column order of a SQL Server Report Services report at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724812/how-can-i-change-the-column-order-of-a-sql-server-report-services-report-at-runt).

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway , very helpful link. I add this reference too:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b900bbac-778e-4241-997a-6368bc36a299/is-it-possible-to-change-the-order-of-column-of-ssrs-report-dynamically?forum=sqlreportingservices .